# Arduino cannot convert 'float' to 'const char*' in initialization

Tags: c++, arduino

```
float diff = 0;
const char* str[] = {"Err: ZPROBE: ",diff};
LCD_ALERTMESSAGEPGM(str);
```

With the code above I get I get this error. Anyone know how to create a single string from `"Err: ZPROBE: "` and a (float) `diff`?

```
exit status 1
cannot convert 'float' to 'const char*' in initializatio
```

Sorry should add that in the environment i'm using -  `'string' : is not a member of 'std',`

Ok now trying this

```
String str = String("Err: ZPROBE: " , diff);
```

but get this

```
call of overloaded 'String(const char [14], float&)' is ambiguous
```

Comment: Use `snprintf`. Or better yet, use `std::string` and pass `c_str()` to the macro.

Comment: I regret to inform you that it's not just Arduino that can't do it, but every C++ compiler in existence because this is not valid C++. If your intentions are really to write C++ code, then open your C++ book to the chapter that explains how to use `std::ostringstream`, and read it.

Comment: For strings in Arduino you should probably use [the Arduino standard `String` class](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/StringObject) (which is *not* the same as the standard C++ `std::string` class).

Comment: Sorry should add that in the environment i'm using -  'string' : is not a member of 'std',

Comment: @RickAstley with String str = String("Err: ZPROBE: " + diff); I get invalid operands of types 'const char [14]' and 'float' to binary 'operator+'

Comment: Read a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), and stop guessing

Comment: I will reiterate that. You will not get very far in C++ by making random guesses how C++ code that needs to do a specific task should look like. C++ is, arguably, the most complicated general purpose programming language in use today. The only way to learn it is in either in a class, with a good instructor, or by reading a C++ book. Trying to randomly put together various bits and pieces of what you think looks like valid C++ code, and then seeing if it works, is a waste of time.

Comment: I understand where you are coming from but I honestly hardly ever touch c++. This is just a simple hack I need to do to an existing program

Comment: @Lee This "quick hack" is essentially someone else writing everything. You are not going to fix it by guessing

Comment: It's hardly guessing, I read the docs and try something to the best of my understanding.

Comment: When you ask about `String str = String("Err: ZPROBE: " + diff)`, you are guessing. It might be an educated guess, but a guess non the less

Comment: From the docs here it looked plausible https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/StringConstructors many languages are capable of of intelligently realising that a string + float should = string

Comment: @Lee - You are still just guessing. And `string` is C++, but `String` is not. And guessing still doesn't work. While `string literal`+ `float` doesn't compile, `string literal`+ `int` *does*, but with a result totally different from the one you expect. Please listen to Sam, and read up on this!

Answer (score 0):

To convert `float` or `double` into a `string`, you can use [`dtostrf()`](http://www.atmel.com/webdoc/avrlibcreferencemanual/group__avr__stdlib_1ga060c998e77fb5fc0d3168b3ce8771d42.html) which is available in the `stdlib.h` header. Also see the reference of [String Object Constructors](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/StringConstructors) to construct `String` objects correctly.